# opendkim-testkey: key not secure, but dnssec is ok

Tags: domain-name-system, opendkim

I'm trying to setup opendkim, but I get this result:

```
# opendkim-testkey  -vvvv -d my.example.com -s 201702
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key '201702._domainkey.my.example.com'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

That should mean DNSSEC is not working.

But according to https://dnssec-debugger.verisignlabs.com/example.com dnssec is fine.

Should I worry?

Comment: The TLD `dom` doesn't yet exist, so `domain.dom` wouldn't have DNSSEC. Your link doesn't state that DNSSEC is fine on `domain.dom`, rather that DNSSEC on the root zone is fine.

Comment: It is obvious that `my.domain.dom` is an example,

Comment: And we cannot help you diagnose DNSSEC issues on a domain which isn't supplied.

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that OpenDKIM is able to use DNSSEC. `key not secure` in this context means that OpenDKIM was not able to verify the key using DNSSEC.

For example, you can use `dig` to see if it reports the AD (authentic data) flag:

```
$ dig yourselector._domainkey.yourdomain.org TXT +dnssec

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> yourselector._domainkey.yourdomain.org TXT +dnssec
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26731
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

...
```

The important bit here is the flag `ad`: it means that whatever resolver was used on the host was able to authenticate the response data with DNSSEC.

For OpenDKIM, you also must make sure that it can use DNSSEC. For example, on Debian the setting `TrustAnchorFile /usr/share/dns/root.key` in the default /etc/opendkim.conf provides the support for DNSSEC capabilities.

Comment: This is the solution. @Lenne you might accept this answer...

Comment: Hi @Lenne , @71GA and @glts I know this answer was a long time ago, but i'm facing the same error as the OP and can't figure out why i'm getting it. 
`dig` command did not show me the `ad` flag, I added the `TrustAnchorFile` but things stayed the same, with or without it. Any more ideas ?  Thanks a lot