# opendkim-testkey: key not secure (file permissions are good and TrustAnchorFile config setting is set)

Tags: email, smtp, dkim, dnssec, opendkim

If I run `sudo opendkim-testkey -d mydomain.com -s selector -vvv`, I get

```
opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
opendkim-testkey: checking key 'selector._domainkey.mydomain.com'
opendkim-testkey: key not secure
opendkim-testkey: key OK
```

and I can't figure out how to fix "key not secure".

If I do `dig selector._domainkey.mydomain.com TXT +dnssec` then the `ad` flag is missing from the answer.

The setting `TrustAnchorFile         /usr/share/dns/root.key` is enabled in `/etc/opendkim.conf`.

Running `ls -ls` in the directory `/etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com` shows

```
4 -rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim 1708 Mar  7 15:32 selector.private
4 -rw------- 1 opendkim opendkim  507 Mar  7 15:32 selector.txt
```

Running `ls -ls` in the directory `/etc/opendkim/keys` shows

```
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 opendkim opendkim 4096 Mar  7 15:32 mydomain.com
```

Running `ls -ls` in the directory `/etc/opendkim` shows

```
4 drwxr-x--- 3 opendkim opendkim 4096 Mar  7 15:32 keys
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim  106 Mar  7 15:31 key.table
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim   44 Mar  7 15:31 signing.table
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 opendkim opendkim   31 Mar  7 15:32 trusted.hosts
```

Running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Related questions that do not solve the problem (and on which I do not have sufficient board cred to comment):

- [opendkim-testkey:key not secure](https://serverfault.com/questions/1048491/opendkim-testkey-key-not-secure)
- [opendkim-testkey:key not secure, but dnssec is ok](https://serverfault.com/questions/834576/opendkim-testkey-key-not-secure-but-dnssec-is-ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the other Q&A’s, this just means that that key is being retrieved without DNSSEC being used.

It doesn’t mean anything is broken or needs to be fixed.

If you like you can set up DNSSEC for your domain (or let your DNS provider do it for you), then you should see `key secure`.